# UrlRewrite Middleware and Client Applications

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I am not even sure if url rewriting will fit my use case but I have a feeling it might (using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite`). I have a client served by my ASP.NET Core project with UseStaticFiles(). This same project also uses the `default` MVC with routes as follows in my startup Configure method:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}");
});
```

My client application does an out of band call which receives a callback from another service and this callback contains a url/hash fragment so that the client application can process whatever is in the url/hash fragment. Lets say this service replies with `/callback#foo='bar'`.

Just some more context, what is happening is that my client app is doing a login from an openid-connect provider, and on login, what happens is you get directed to the provider, this provider redirects you back to your application with the token in the hash fragment (on successful login), so when my ASP.NET Core application gets the request `callback#foo=bar` I want it to serve my static application in `wwwroot` with the hash fragment in place so my client side app can consume the hash fragment (which is the token returned by the provider)

Comment: I might be missing something, but what is the question here?

Comment: Basically I type localhost:5000/callback#foo=bar into my browser, I want it to serve my client with the hash fragment in place so that my client can consume the hash fragment. Instead, my app 404s because I have no controller configured for endpoint /callback.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would like to serve a custom url for static files from the wwwroot. In that case,you can do this

`app.Map("callback#foo=bar", subApp => subApp.UseStaticFiles());`

Comment: will this work even when `foo` and `bar` are variable?